# Having problems with Backup migrate and file system for custom back up settings

Tags: backups

I am trying to set up backup migrate but keep getting this error with my custom destinations:

```
The specified file C:\source\sites\defaut\files\tmp\bacE255.tmp.mysql.gz.info could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.
```

On this       URL:*admin/config/system/backup_migrate/settings/destination/edit/backups_bruno*

### Settings

Destination name:
**Backups_Bruno**

Directory path:
**/sites/default/files/backups_bruno**

On this URL: 
*admin/config/media/file-system*

### Settings

Public file system path:**sites/default/files**

Private file system path:**sites/default/files/private**

Temporary directory:**sites/default/files/tmp**

Comment: looks like a permission issue, you need to give a write permission to your tmp folder.

Comment: Permissions are fine for windows 7, checked permission for media and backup migrate, fine also...???